# Wamp unable to start in windows2016

Tags: windows, wampserver

I am are unable to start Wamp server because mysql does not starts. The same Wamp server was working fine earlier. please have a look at below log

```
C:\wamp32\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin>httpd.exe

[alias:warn] [pid 13596:tid 324] AH00671: The Alias directive in C
:/wamp32/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/conf/httpd.conf at line 610 will probably never match because i    
t overlaps an earlier Alias.

(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH
00072: make_sock: -could not bind to address [::]:443

(OS 10013)An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.  : AH

00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:443

AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down

AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Netstat command

```
    \wamp32\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin>netstat -aon | find "443"
TCP    0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
```

Task Kill

```
C:\wamp32\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin>taskkill /f /pid 4
ERROR: The process with PID 4 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.
```

Thanks

Comment: If its on Pid 4 then its probably because you have IIS and/or associated software running

Answer (score 1):

Possibly some service already uses 443 port.
You can use `netstat -aon | Select-String "443"` command in powershell to determine it.

Comment: yeah, but i tried to kill the process, get below error C:\wamp32\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin>taskkill /f /pid 4
ERROR: The process with PID 4 could not be terminated.
Reason: Access is denied.

Comment: This is system service or role. You need to stop service or delete role

Comment: With high probability it is IIS or RemoteAccess. Check if it is in running state and try to disable.